# How to trigger a GTM Tag with a div class

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager

I want to trigger a Google Tag Manager tag with the text within a div class. The text is "Accommodation offer successfully edited". I've tried element ids and classes to no success. Do you have any recommendation? Is this even possible?

There is nothing else on the page that makes it unique so I really have to go with what is inside this div

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
                <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close close-sm" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                Accommodation offer successfully edited
            </div>
```

Comment: What is the action taken on the div, is it a click? If it's a click, you can use the Click Text variable and, possibly, write some custom JS to determine if that matches the text on the page.

Comment: unfortunately no. No action is taken on the div. Its a simple alert text that is displayed on the page

Comment: Then  trigger your tag based on the presence of the div class and the text.

Comment: Thanks nyuen, that can be a good idea. Are you able to shed some light on how would you go and do that?